# Ansible: How to check if an Artifactory Repository exist or not, if it exists update the Repository configuration, if not create the Repository

Tags: api, ansible, repository, artifactory

How we can use `when` condition in an Ansible playbook to check if an Artifactory Repository exist or not, if it exists update the Repository configuration, if not create the Repository. For all, create and update I am using the REST API.

Here I am using the REST API from JFrog Artifactory, I don't want to write any Python or Shell script. I need to do all with Ansible by using [Conditionals](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html).

I have tried:

```yaml
 - name: Update Repository Configuration
    uri:
      url: (url)/api/repositories/docker-remote
      method: POST
      headers:
        Content-Type: application/json
      body_format: json
      body: "{{ lookup('file','/docker-remote.json') }}"
      follow_redirects: all
      url_username: "user"
      url_password: "pass"
      force_basic_auth: yes
      status_code: 200
      return_content: yes
    delegate_to: localhost
    when: status_code == 200
    register: result

  - name: Create Repository
    uri:
      url: (url)/api/repositories/docker-remote
      method: PUT
      headers:
        Content-Type: application/json
      body_format: json
      body: "{{ lookup('file','docker-remote.json') }}"
      follow_redirects: all
      url_username: "user"
      url_password: "pass"
      force_basic_auth: yes
      status_code: 200
      return_content: yes
    delegate_to: localhost
    register: result
    when: status_code == 400
```

Comment: Don't stop typing after you showed what your tried. Tell us what is wrong with it and you have already tried to fix your problem. Please read [ask] and pay attention to the [mre] section. As a pure guess at this point: `status_code` is probably undefined and I suspect you want to use `result.status` from your registered var. The other problem I see is that your are registering 2 task with the same var name meaning you override any value from the first when running the second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've almost achieved your goal. Since Ansible is a tool for [Configuration Management](https://www.ansible.com/use-cases/configuration-management), one need only to make sure that there is a Desired State configured.

> *... check if an Artifactory Repository exist or not, if it exists update the Repository configuration, if not create the Repository ...*

In other words, there is no need to check before or to do something like IF THEN ELSE. It is only necessary to declare how the final state should look like. Based on your already given example you could proceed further with the following ...

A sample repository configuration set in JSON representation, `TEST.json`

```json
{
  "key" : "TEST",
  "rclass" : "local",
  "repoLayoutRef": "simple-default",
  "description" : "Local generic test repository",
  "url" : "https://<yourRepositoryURL>/artifactory/TEST",
  "packageType": "Generic"
}
```

and a sample test playbook `create_repository.yml`

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: no
  gather_facts: no

  vars:

    API_URL: "<yourRepositoryURL>/artifactory/api"
    REST_API_ENDPOINT: "repositories" # since there are also access and security ...
    RKEY: "TEST" # aka REPOSITORY_KEY

  tasks:

  - name: Read in repository configuration
    include_vars:
      file: "{{ RKEY }}.json"
      name: CONFIG
    when: not ansible_check_mode

  - name: Make sure repository is created
    local_action:
      module: uri
      url: "https://{{ API_URL }}/{{ REST_API_ENDPOINT }}/{{ RKEY }}"
      method: PUT
      url_username: "{{ ansible_user }}"
      url_password: "{{ ansible_password }}"
      validate_certs: yes
      body_format: json
      body: "{{ CONFIG }}"
      status_code: 200,400
    register: PUT
    failed_when: false
    when: not ansible_check_mode

  - name: Make sure repository is in desired state
    local_action:
      module: uri
      url: "https://{{ API_URL }}/{{ REST_API_ENDPOINT }}/{{ RKEY }}"
      method: POST
      url_username: "{{ ansible_user }}"
      url_password: "{{ ansible_password }}"
      validate_certs: yes
      body_format: json
      body: "{{ CONFIG }}"
      status_code: 200
    when: not ansible_check_mode and PUT.status == 400

  - name: Gather current repository configuration, if there is one
    local_action:
      module: uri
      url: "https://{{ API_URL }}/{{ REST_API_ENDPOINT }}/{{ RKEY }}"
      method: GET
      url_username: "{{ ansible_user }}"
      url_password: "{{ ansible_password }}"
      validate_certs: yes
      return_content: yes
      status_code: 200,400
      body_format: json
    register: GET
    check_mode: false

  - name: Show repository configuration, if there is one
    debug:
      msg: "{{ GET.json }}"
    check_mode: false
```

to call via

```bash
sshpass -p ${PASSWORD} ansible-playbook --user ${ACCOUNT} --ask-pass create_repository.yml --check
sshpass -p ${PASSWORD} ansible-playbook --user ${ACCOUNT} --ask-pass create_repository.yml
```

If the given repository configuration is not available within Artifactory, the first REST API call will result into the creation of it and an status code of `200`. After that there would be no need for an update. Therefore, `when: PUT.status == 400`.

If the given repository configuration is already available within Artifactory, the first REST API call result into an status code of `400`, which is then considered not as an error. After that another REST API call makes sure that the configuration is in the desired state.